# Can you use Facebook "Test Users" to test a Messenger Bot?

Tags: facebook, messenger, facebook-test-users

I'm currently trying to make a Messenger Bot with the Messenger Platform. I have a Facebook page, app, everything set up, it currently works when I (an admin for the app) message it. So, I made a few [test users](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users) to test it with more users. But, whenever I login as a test user, I can't seem to message the page. As a test user, I can't access the page, and a direct Messenger link gives an "access denied" page.

As an admin, I tried to add this test users as a "Tester" under the roles, but I also get more "access denied" messages.

So, is there a way to use a Facebook Test User to interact with my pre-approved Messenger Bot?

Comment: Same problem here. Did you find any solution ?

Comment: Yes, I did. Here's the workaround:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/230322797329131/?hc_location=ufi

Comment: @AlexGarcia I don't get your solution, the article you point to is about the bot not being able to reply to the test user, not about the test user being able to access the app page, which was the original question. Could you be more specific?

Comment: The original question is about inability to test a Messenger Bot using test users.  The URL posted by Alex above solves this problem by creating a separate page to which the bot can be plugged (possibly, in addition to its regular page) in order to be testable by the test user.     Great answer, @AlexGarcia!  If you don't mind, I'll post it as an answer for easier search. Ping me if you would like to post it yourself.

Answer (score 7):

A working workaround was described here: [http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/230322797329131/?hc_location=uf‌i](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/230322797329131/?hc_location=uf%E2%80%8Ci)

Kudos to Alex Garcia himself :)